# What is the correct interpretation for the integral of a differential $k$-form in terms of typical vector-calculus multiple integrals?

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms

**Preliminary context**:

Prof. Kennan Crane from CMU posted a course on discrete differential geometry. I've been able to follow so far, until [Lecture 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Z2V3dMNhbQ&list=PL9_jI1bdZmz0hIrNCMQW1YmZysAiIYSSS&index=9&t=9s). Please let me give some context on how he defines the stuff before posing my question. Basically, a vector is defined in terms of its components as a linear combination of the basis vectors denoted with $\left\{e_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right\}_{i=1}^n$. Moreover $k$-vectors are defined as linear combinations of $e_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge e_{i_k}$ for some indices $i_1,\dots,i_k$ (see [Lecture 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paEKgbiCyPk&list=PL9_jI1bdZmz0hIrNCMQW1YmZysAiIYSSS&index=5&t=3240s)). Then, it is explained that forms are basically a generalization of covectors (in euclidean space, the dual of vectors which can be thought as row vectors vs column vectors), which are linear transformations from vectors to scalars. Then, covectors (or 1-forms) are given as linear combinations of the basis 1-forms $\{dx_i\}_{i=1}^n$, and $k$-forms are linear combinations of $dx_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{i_k}$. Until this point, the symbols $dx_i$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ are not related to derivatives or differentials, but are just basis vectors/forms. Prof. Crane explains that $k$-forms are meant to be applied to $k$-vectors in order to obtain a scalar measure. For example the area of the parallelepiped $u\wedge v$ for two vectors $u,v$ can be measured by a 2-form $\alpha\wedge\beta$ for two 1-forms $\alpha,\beta$, just scaled by the "size" of $\alpha,\beta$. In particular the concrete relation between forms and vectors basis is given by
$$
dx_i\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right) = \delta_{ij}
$$
where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta. Moreover, the application $(\alpha\wedge \beta)(u, v)=\alpha(u)\beta(v)-\alpha(v)\beta(u)$ which can be written as a determinant (and generalized for the $k$-forms).

**Now comes my questions** all regarding Lecture 7.

1. At 6:23, the motivation behind the definition of the integral of a 2-form $\omega$ is that it is the summation of $\omega_{p_i}$ (evaluate $\omega$ at the point $p_i$) applied to a pair of vectors $u_i=u({p_i}),v_i=v(p_i)$ (for some vector fields $u,v$) along with the whole region $\Omega$:
   $$
   \sum_{i}\omega_{p_i}(u_i,v_i)\to \int_{\Omega}\omega
   $$ However, in 8:31 we have the integral of a form $(x+xy)dx\wedge dy$ over $\Omega$ which is the unit square. Then, somehow it follows that
   $$
   \int_{\Omega} (x+xy)dx\wedge dy = \int_0^1\int_0^1 (x+xy)dxdy
   $$
   where I don't see to what vectors $u,v$ are we applying the form $dx\wedge dy$. Mainly, I'm lost at the motivation behind the interpretation of the 2-form $dx\wedge dy$ as a scalar $dxdy$ inside the integral, given that $dx$ and $dy$ were supposed to be just basis forms (covectors). The following may be too hand wavy, but I'm trying to get intuition about this: My thoughts are that we make a parallelepiped spanned by the vectors $u=(dx)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $v=(dy)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ where here $dx$ and $dy$ are small displacements in the directions $\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$. This parallelepiped has area $dxdy$, and we can measure such area by the form $dx\wedge dy$. Hence, we use $dx\wedge dy$ to measure this parallelepiped obtaining $dx\wedge dy(u,v)=dxdy$. However, this reasoning seems artificial to me (since we didnt't take advantage of the notation dx,dy for the basis covectors, instead we used other displacements $dxdy$ different from the basis covectors). It would be better to have defined $dx(\frac{\partial}{\partial x})$="$dx$" (where the second $dx$ is the displacement and not the covector) instead of $dx(\frac{\partial}{\partial x})=1$ as we did before (move the displacements $dx$ and $dy$ to the definition of the covectors $dx$ and $dy$ instead of the parallelepiped $u\wedge v$).
2. At 14:00, one finds the integral of a 1-form $\alpha=dy$ over the circular curve $S^1$ (parametrized as $\gamma:[0,2\pi)\to\mathbb{R}^2, \gamma(s) = (\cos(s),\sin(s))$), which somehow results in:
   $$
   \int_{S^1}\alpha = \int_0^{2\pi} \alpha_\gamma(T(s))ds
   $$
   where $T(s)$ is the tangent vector to $\gamma(s)$. Here we are clearly applying the form $\alpha$ to a vector, different from my previous doubt. Howeve, different than before, instead of using $dy$ as the differential in the integral, we introduced an additional $ds$ where I don't know where it came from.

**I already know how to compute this integrals, and I know that their expressions make sense from the typical vector calculus perspective. But I want to understand what is the systematic way of translating the integral of $k$-forms to a multiple-integral. My confusion comes from the fact that it appears that very different "rules" were used to translate $\int_{\Omega} (x+xy)dx\wedge dy = \int_0^1\int_0^1 (x+xy)dxdy$ as in the case $\int_{S^1}\alpha = \int_0^{2\pi} \alpha_\gamma(T(s))ds$.**

Comment: Does he not discuss the concept of orientation? This is crucial to converting an integral of a differential form into a multiple integral.

Comment: For example, if you are calculating $\int_C \theta$, then $C$ must be an *oriented* curve, which simply means you have to draw an arrow on the curve indicating a direction of travel. In 2D it's a little more complicated.

Comment: Yes, he discusses precisely what you wrote, and I understand that (mainly since I get the concept from typical vector calculus). Moreover, he discusses the concept of the orientation for the k-forms and k-vectors, which leads to the anti-symmetry of the operator $\wedge$. However, I am not able to translate those concepts to the actual computation. Thanks.

Comment: If you're using the standard orientation on $\mathbb{R}^2$, you first write the differential form as $(\dots)\,dx\wedge dy$. So if you have $a\,dy\wedge dx$, you have to rewrite it as $-a\,dx\wedge dy$. Once you've written the differential form in this normalized form, then you can convert it into a multiple integral, where it doesn't matter what order you integrate in.

Comment: More generally, if you have a surface, $\Phi(u,v) = (x(u,v), y(u,v),z(u,v))$ with orientation given by a non-tangent vector $n(u,v)$ along the surface and want to integrate a form $\Theta = a\,dy\wedge dz + b\,dz\wedge dx + c\,dx\wedge dy$, you have to first check whether the parameterized orientation agrees with the orientation given by $n$. You do this by checking the sign $n\cdot(\partial_u\Phi\times \partial_v\Phi)$. If this is positive, write the integrand as $(\dots)\,du\wedge dv$, otherwise as $(\dots)\,dv\wedge du$. Then convert to multiple integral.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get that. However, I don't see the motivation behind defining $dx\wedge dy$ (in canonical order) as $dxdy$ inside the integral. Particularly since the 1-form $dy$ is not used in the integral in the second example I put. If the "rule" will be to put the differentials in canonical order first, and then integrate (intepret dxdy not as a form but as the differentials in the multiple integral), why does this rule does't hold for the integral of the 1-form.

Comment: In fact, orientation plays a role for even the Calculus 1 integral. When you write $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ you are integrating on an oriented interval, where $a$ is the start and $b$ the end of the interval. Notice that in the definition, there is no need to assume $a \le b$. If $a \ge b$, you're simply integrating over the interval with the opposite of the usual orientation.

Comment: You replace $dx\wedge dy$ by $dx\,dy$ only if you want to use the standard orientation of $\mathbb{R}^2$. You could use the opposite orientation. In that case you would instead replace $dy\wedge dx$ by $dx\,dy$.

Comment: Thanks @Deane. I think I understand the orientation aspect. However, my question is more related to when do we translate differential forms to actual differentials to compute an integral. In the 2-form $dx\wedge dy$ is translated as $dxdy$, I'm fine with that. But in the second example, the 1-form $dy$ is not translated as a differential $dy$ in the integral, but an additional $ds$ appeared from somewhere. That's mostly what's bothering me.

Comment: Sorry. I should have read the second part more carefully. That does seem wrong to me. Since $y = \sin(s)$, $dy = \cos(s)\,ds$.

Comment: Integration of forms on surfaces is defined using the pullback: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(differential_geometry)#Pullback_of_differential_forms If $\alpha$ is a form on a surface $M$ with compact support in an open set $U \subset M$ and $\phi \colon O \to U$ is a parameterization of $U$ where $O \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is open, then $$\int_{U}\alpha = \int_{O}\phi^*\alpha.$$ Forms on open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^m$ can be integrated as levap wrote, essentially by substituting $dx_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx_m$ with $d(x_1, \dots, x_m)$ and then doing a Riemann/Lebesgue integral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say $\varphi \colon U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is an embedding where $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ is an open subset so that $\varphi(U)$ is a $k$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\omega$ be a $k$-form on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Write $\varphi = \varphi(x^1, \dots, x^k)$. The integral of $\omega$ over $\varphi(U)$ is then
$$ \int_{\varphi(U)} \omega = \int_{U} \omega_{\varphi(x^1, \dots, x^k)} \left( \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x^1}, \dots, \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x^k} \right) \, dx^1 \dots dx^k. $$

Here, the left hand side is an integral of a different $k$-form on a submanifold while the right hand side is the Riemann/Lebesgue integral of a function over an open set (so there are no wedges and the notation $dx^1 \dots dx^k$ is just symbolic). More explicitly, at any point $(x^1, \dots, x^k)$ in the domain $U$ of your parametrization, the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x^1}, \dots, \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x^k}$ give you a special ($\varphi$-dependent) basis for the tangent space to $\varphi(U)$ at $\varphi(x^1,\dots,x^k)$. At each point you plug this basis into the $k$-form (in the specific order!) and get a number. This process gives you a function which you then integrate over $U$ (in the sense of Riemann/Lebesgue integral).

Given this description, let's see how your two examples fit in:

1. When $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is an open subset and $\omega$ is a two-form on $\mathbb{R^2}$, we take $\varphi$ to be the inclusion. Let's write $\omega = f(x,y) \, dx \wedge dy$. Then
   $$ \int_{\varphi(\Omega)} \omega = \int_{\Omega} \omega = \int_{\Omega} \left( f(x,y) \, dx \wedge dy \right) \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right) \, dx dy = \int_{\Omega} f(x,y) dxdy$$
   as $\left( dx \wedge dy \right) \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right) \equiv 1$. Thus, the direct effect is just "removing the wedge symbol" and treating it as a regular integral of a function.
2. For the case of the circle, take $U = (0,2\pi)$ and $\varphi(s) = \alpha(s) = (\cos(s), \sin(s))$. Then
   $$ \int_{\varphi(U)} \alpha = \int_{S^1 \setminus \{ \textrm{pt} \}} \alpha = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \alpha_{\varphi(s)} \left( \alpha'(s) \right) \, ds.$$
   In the particular case $\alpha = dy$, we have
   $$ \alpha_{\varphi(s)} \left( \alpha'(s) \right) = dy \left( -\sin(s) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \cos(s) \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right) = \cos(s) $$
   so you are left with the integral
   $$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos(s) \, ds. $$
   Strictly speaking, this calculates the integral of $\alpha$ over $S^1 \setminus \{ \textrm{pt} \}$ and not over $S^1$ but a point has measure zero in $S^1$ and so can be ignored in the calculation under appropriate assumptions.

Comment: Thanks sir! I think I got it... just a couple of questions. what is $\{pt\}$? is the point corresponding to $\alpha(2\pi)$? are we ignoring it for some reason? And another thing, if the symbolic differentials are there anyway in the Riemann/Lebesgue integral, what is the motivation of using "$dx,dy$" as basis for the differential forms? (the symbols/notation I mean)

Comment: @FeedbackLooper: Yeah, this is the point corresponding to $\alpha(2\pi)$. I'm not sure I understand the second question. One uses differential forms to make everything "coordinate independent". On $\mathbb{R}^2$ you have a set of natural coordinates $(x,y)$, a natural basis $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ for the tangent spaces (which is naturally identified with the standard basis $e_1,e_2$) and a natural dual basis $dx,dy$ but of course you can work with other coordinates. If you use polar coordinates, you will work with $dr,d\theta$ instead and so on.

Comment: My point was regarding what was the point of using the notation with the "d". From the typical vector calculus perspective, one would use $y=sin(s)$ then $dy=cos(s)ds$. However, in this other perspective, one puts the $ds$ anyway, regarless of the $dy$. I mean this last question is only regarding the motivation behind the notation, so it may not be too imoportant, I have to think about this myself. Thanks sir!